# How to open a file on Nautilus File Dialog through HTTP URL?

Tags: nautilus, browser

It's available on Windows. For example, when a browser file input ask you to select a file from your computer, you can type a url as a location. And it's going to be downloaded as a temporary file and be selected for input.

Can we do that on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
You can have a look at the bug and discussion on this [page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/service-discovery-applet/+bug/113092).
A workaround is also listed on this page,which suggests use of `xdg-open` for url

**Opening a file on your Computer**:
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.You can enter into address bar now.
This option is also available in the menu.Select *Go>Location*.
You can do that using command-line too.Like to open *Downloads* folder in nautilus,type `nautilus ~/Downloads`

Comment: Thanks. But you didn't get it. :) I want to open a file through its HTTP URL.

Comment: Sorry.Title was misleading,corrected it now.

Comment: Sorry too. Changed to HTTP URL. :)

Comment: How to edit Nautilus to use xdg-open?

Comment: I think that's possible only by hacking into nautilus source code.